# DataTables: How to set classes to table row cells (but not to table header cells!)

Tags: javascript, datatables

i have a really nice style for my tables.

*{ sorry links no more working }*

I had to add sClass so that new rows (added by fnAddData) get the right classes.

Unfortunately that ruins my layout, becouse these classes are also added to my table-header cells!

*{ sorry links no more working }*

How can I configure sClass to apply only for TBODY cells?

**To clarify:**

```
  var rolesTable = $('#roles').dataTable({
      "aoColumns": [
        { "mDataProp": "id", "sClass": "avo-lime-h avo-heading-white" },
        { "mDataProp": "name", "sClass": "avo-light" },
        { "mDataProp": "module", "sClass": "avo-light" },
        { "mDataProp": "description", "sClass": "avo-light" },
        { "mDataProp": null, "bSearchable": false, "bSortable": false, 
          "sDefaultContent": '<button type="button" name="add" class="btn"><i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i></button>' }, 
      ],
  }); // end od dataTable
```

This way when i call

```
rolesTable.fnAddData( { 
    "id": 10, 
    "name": "testname", 
    "module": "testmodule", 
    "description": "testdescription" 
} );
```

then the added row looks like this:

```
<tr>
    <td class="avo-lime-h avo-heading-white">10</td>
    <td class="avo-light">testname</td>
    <td class="avo-light">testmodule</td>
    <td class="avo-light">testdescription</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

AND that is perfectly **OK**

** the problem is ** that this setting also adds these classes to:

```
<thead>
    <tr> (...) </tr>
</thead>
```

table head cells... which I do not want

Comment: Please post the code relevant to the question. Ideally, **in addition** to the code in the question body itself, please add a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/jquery/1.7.1/) example of your problem. It will help us help you.

Comment: i didn't know i can mark "accepted" without upvoting an answer... and until recently my score was too low to be able to upvote

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Solution to my problem was:** useing fnRowCallback instead of sClass to set classes to new rows.

```
  var rolesTable = $('#roles').dataTable({
      "aoColumns": [
        { "mDataProp": "id" },
        { "mDataProp": "name" },
        { "mDataProp": "module" },
        { "mDataProp": "description" },
        { "mDataProp": null, "bSearchable": false, "bSortable": false, 
          "sDefaultContent": '<button type="button" name="add" class="btn btn-round"><i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i></button>' }, 
      ],
      "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
          $('td:eq(0)', nRow).addClass( "avo-lime-h avo-heading-white" );
          $('td:eq(1),td:eq(2),td:eq(3)', nRow).addClass( "avo-light" );
        }
  }); // end od dataTable
```

Comment: The problem with this code is that you're trying `addClass` on every draw of the table. This might lead to performance problems in some scenarios. A better solution would be to add the class after table init and after dynamically adding data. See the thread [here](http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/comment/34602) for discussion.

Answer (score 6):

Since you are only using sClass to apply styling to the table the simple solution to your problem is to modify the CSS itself to only apply to the td elements.

Old CSS style:

```
.avo-light {
    color: blue;
}
```

New CSS style:

```
td.avo-light {
    color: blue;
}
```

This way the CSS will only effect the cells you are interested in applying the style to despite sClass being applied to th elements as well.

I realize this question is a little old, but I find it substantially more modular than the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

Set the default classes before.

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses.sStripeOdd = '';

$.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses.sStripeEven = '';
```

For further references see here 
http://www.datatables.net/styling/custom_classes

Answer (score 2):

```
  let table = $("#myTable").dataTable();
  table.rows().every(function(rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop){
    $(this.node().cells[0]).addClass('red');
    $(this.node().cells[1]).addClass('blue');
  }
```

After the table is rendered, iterate through all rows with the JavaScript selector of each row and make whatever changes you want. This addresses the performance concerns brought up by gamliela in loostr's answer. [DataTables rows().every() documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().every())

Comment: Worked for me. I was loading data via Ajax so had to wrap this with initComplete - https://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete